# How to apply text opacity with fading out gradient?

Tags: css

I have a container with scrolling content (white text, black background).

Like it is possible to apply [fading out opacity to the background of a div](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), I would like to apply opacity only to the bottom of the text within the container, so that it looks like the text is fading out when you scroll down.

Usually, you apply opacity to text like so:

```
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
```

How do you add a gradient to this, i.e. changing levels of opacity from top (opacity 100%) to bottom (opacity 0%) of the container?

I unsuccessfully tried this:

```
color: linear-gradient( bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
```

Comment: You would have to use some form of absolutely positioned overlay to the parent div rather than trying to affect the text itself but it would take some fiddling to get the positioning and dimensions right.

Answer (score 0):

You need an element to simulate the gradient.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T5pd7/

```
.gradient{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0.0));
}
```